# How to insert this full article?

Tags: php, sql, pivot, mariadb

this PHP-line:

```
$xx_val = (string) $xx;
```

generate the following output:

```
string(16) "XYZ1"
string(11) "XYZ2"
string(12) "XZY1"
string(19) "XZY2"
string(34) "8997451"
```

when I insert it to my db:

```
        $xx_val = (string) $xx;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO attributes (article) VALUES ($xx_val)";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "\n\n### DONE ###\n\n";}
        else {
            echo "\n\n### ERROR ###" . $sql . "\n" . $conn->error . "\n\n";}

    +-----+-----------+------------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+
    | id  | article   | attr1      | attr2  | attr3    | attr4     | attr5       |
    +-----+-----------+------------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+
    | 001 | XYZ1      | NULL       | NULL   | NULL     | NULL      | NULL        |
    | 002 | XYZ2      | NULL       | NULL   | NULL     | NULL      | NULL        |
    | 003 | XZY1      | NULL       | NULL   | NULL     | NULL      | NULL        |
    | 004 | XZY2      | NULL       | NULL   | NULL     | NULL      | NULL        |
    | 005 | 8997451   | NULL       | NULL   | NULL     | NULL      | NULL        |
    +-----+-----------+------------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

but I would like to have all the attributes in one row:

```
    +-----+-----------+------------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+
    | id  | article   | attr1      | attr2  | attr3    | attr4     | attr5       |
    +-----+-----------+------------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+
    | 001 | 1         | XYZ1       | XYZ2   | XZY1     | XZY2      | 8997451     |
    +-----+-----------+------------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

I'm pretty sure that my "insert into" is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: you insert your values only into article, try to add others columns too.

Comment: Also, add a closing `"` to your `$sql`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Comment: First, thanks for your help :) 1. Added the `"` @kerbholz
2. `$sql = "INSERT INTO attributes (article, attr1) VALUES ($xx_val, $xx_val);`
when I go like this I get a error:
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'XYZ1)' at line 1` @Sfili_81

Comment: Please update your question to include all the relevant code and and information. Putting code in comments makes it hard to read.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson marked the correct answer and edited the title, hope it's ok now

Comment: Does your table have 2 columns?  Or 6?  If 2, follow the "pivot" tag.

Comment: I have 6 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update your SQL query, it should looks like:

```
$sql = "
  INSERT INTO attributes (article , attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4 , attr5)
  VALUES ('$article', '$attr1', '$attr2', '$attr3', '$attr4', '$attr5')
";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

and now you have to have variables `$article, $attr1, $attr2, $attr3, $attr4, $attr5` which contains appropriate values.

And when you doing `$xx_val = (string) $xx;` please don't forget about validate and escape actual value, with purpose to prevent `SQL-Injection`.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting the qoutes around the string values like so:

```
INSERT INTO attributes (article, attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4, attr5) 
VALUES ('$xx_val', '$xx_val', '$xx_val', '$xx_val', '$xx_val', '$xx_val')
```